# getting error while pushing react app to github repo - "error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining"

Tags: git, create-react-app, github-pages, rpc, git-push

```
E:\my-portfolio>git push -u origin main
Enumerating objects: 72, done.
Counting objects: 100% (72/72), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (69/69), done.
Writing objects: 100% (72/72), 5.76 MiB | 15.43 MiB/s, done.
Total 72 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: There are numerous possible causes. The most common at this point seems to be badly configured firewalls that intercept https traffic. If that is the case, consider using ssh instead of https.